# Put shared definitions in an external file

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following construct

```
typedef struct Article {
    char * word;
    int code;
} Artcle;
```

And I want a bunch of files to have access to what amounts to:

```
Article THE = (Article) {.word="The", .code=87};
Article A   = (Article) {.word="A",   .code=79};
Article AN  = (Article) {.word="An",  .code=80};
```

What would be the proper way to put this into a shared `article.c/h` file? My first thought was doing:

```
// article.h
typedef struct Article {
    char * word;
    int code;
} Artcle;
Article THE = (Article) {.word="The", .code=87};
Article A   = (Article) {.word="A",   .code=79};
Article AN  = (Article) {.word="An",  .code=80};
```

But this is obviously wrong with the multiple definitions for the `Article`s. What would be the proper way to do this then?

---

One possible way to do this (I thought) was:

```
// article.h
typedef struct Article {
    char * word;
    int code;
} Artcle;
extern Article THE;
extern Article A;
extern Article AN;

// article.c
#include "article.h"
Article THE = (Article) {.word="The", .code=87};
Article A   = (Article) {.word="A",   .code=79};
Article AN  = (Article) {.word="An",  .code=80};
```

Additionally, what are these 'shared variables' referred to as?

Comment: define the constants in one .c file and use 'extern Article THE =',... in the .h files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last approach looks good, and is the normal way to do this.  The only thing I'd change is that it's not necessary to use [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) to initialize objects.  You can simply write `Article THE = {.word="The", .code=87};` and so on, without the `(Article)` cast-like syntax.

> Additionally, what are these 'shared variables' referred to as?

They're simply global variables.  Or, to be more formal, they are variables with file scope, external linkage, and static storage duration.

Note that if you don't intend to modify them over the course of the program, you should declare and define them as `const`.  Global variables are generally considered a poor programming practice, but global constants don't have the same issues.

Comment: thanks, one question. When do you have to use the `(Article)` notation and when can you skip over that, like you show above?

Comment: @carl.hiass: Roughly speaking, you never need compound literals when initializing a newly declared variable, but they can be used if you want an "anonymous" object of the struct type elsewhere.  Examples are a little too long for this comment, so maybe you should ask this as a new question.  But they're a relatively obscure language feature.  Anywhere you might use them, you could just as well declare and initialize a temporary variable instead, and that may well result in clearer code anyway.